# syntax error - token ";" inserted before "{"

Tags: c, syntax-error

I wrote a function for ADC to read a gear value. I am constantly getting this error but I don't know what to do with it.. Suggestions?
My code is:

```
void MAIN_vInit(void)
{

   void read_bremspedal();    //This is my ADC read function prototype
   PSW_IEN        =  0;          


  ///  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ///  Configuration of the System Clock:
  ///  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ///  - VCO clock used, input clock is connected
  ///  - input frequency is 8,00 MHz

  MAIN_vUnlockProtecReg();     // unlock write security

  MAIN_vChangeFreq();          // load PLL control register

  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  //   SCU Interrupt Disable configuration:
  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  SCU_INTDIS     =  0xFFFF;      // SCU Interrupt Disable Register

  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  //   Initialization of the Peripherals:
  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------

  //   initializes the Parallel Ports
  IO_vInit();

  //   initializes the Capture / Compare Unit 61 (CCU61)
  CCU61_vInit();

  //   initializes the Analog / Digital Converter  (ADC0)
  ADC0_vInit();

  //   initializes the MultiCAN Module (CAN)
  CAN_vInit();


  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  //   Initialization of the Bank Select registers:
  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------


  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  //   SCU Interrupt Source Selection configuration:
  //   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  SCU_ISSR       =  0x0000;      // SCU Interrupt Source Select Register

  // USER CODE BEGIN (Init,3)

  // USER CODE END

  MAIN_vLockProtecReg();       // lock write security

  //   globally enable interrupts
  PSW_IEN        =  1;          

} 

 while(1)
  {

   // USER CODE BEGIN (Main,13)

      //Bremspedal

      void read_bremspedal(){   //syntax error - token ";" inserted before "{"
      ADC0_vStartSeq0ReqChNum(0,0,1,3);
      uwbremsen = ADC0_uwGetResultData(RESULT_REG_1);
      uwbremsen >>= 4;
      if(uwbremsen) {            // wenn gebremest!
      CAN_MODATA4LL = uwbremsen;
      CAN_vTransmit(4);         //Rekuperation signal senden
      IO_vSetPin(IO_P10_0);     // Nicht Schalten signal
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing parenthesis before the `while` loop.

Comment: Can not be used  local function in standard C.

Comment: Small nit:  You should use int main(void){...} per C99:  5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters:
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the function "void read_bremspedal(){" inside of the while loop. Also, you are trying to write a while loop that is not inside of any function at all. Reverse the lines of code and it should work. The following should at least compile:

```
void read_bremspedal(){
  // USER CODE BEGIN (Main,13)

  //Bremspedal
  while(1) {
    ADC0_vStartSeq0ReqChNum(0,0,1,3);
    uwbremsen = ADC0_uwGetResultData(RESULT_REG_1);
    uwbremsen >>= 4;
    if(uwbremsen) {            // wenn gebremest!
      CAN_MODATA4LL = uwbremsen;
      CAN_vTransmit(4);         //Rekuperation signal senden
      IO_vSetPin(IO_P10_0);     // Nicht Schalten signal
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!

*Note* - It could just be the copy/paste but making sure you have the correct number of open and close parens/braces is much easier when you use proper indentation. Always indent at least 1 (probably 2-4 spaces) after every open curly brace. That should help some in the future!

Comment: Thanks a lot drew_w for ur reply.
I have tried ur suggestion,but the error remains.Actually I have here MAIN.h and MAIN.c and the while(1) loop is in MAIN.c under void main(void) function.I also want to create my function in void main(void).
Can u plz give me some more useful suggestions,so that i get rid of this syntax error.Don't u think,the error may be due to missing of some header file in MAIN.h.

Comment: "I also want to create my function in `void main(void)`." You can't. Put it above the `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot glglgl for ur comment.i got it...